# How do you make a customization on the chapter page

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I can't figure out how to modify it so that it looks like the image below.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\newline\chaptertitlename\}{150pt}{\huge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The Chapter Name}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possibility. The chapter title is typeset raggedright, on a width equal to the width of the large "Chapter".

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength{\mytitlewidth}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \settowidth{\mytitlewidth}{\normalfont\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont\chaptername}
}

\newcommand{\setchaptertitle}[1]{\parbox[t]{\mytitlewidth}{\raggedright#1}}
\newcommand{\setchapternumber}{%
  \smash{\raisebox{-.25\height}{\fontsize{100}{0}\selectfont\thechapter}}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont}
  {\chaptername\ \setchapternumber}
  {15pt}
  {\huge\setchaptertitle}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{12}
\chapter{The chapter title that can go on several lines}

\end{document}
```

Adjust to suit. I wouldn't use boldface.

---

[image]

Comment: Why not use boldface? Thanks a lot for the answer, I'll experiment a bit with it :)

Comment: @FilipEkberg I find that Times (here TeX Gyre Termes) at big sizes is already sufficiently heavy. Bold face would be too much.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. One last thing, when I added this to a file that I've been working on it gave me a lot of "bad box(es)".
Any particular reason for that?
It's complaining about overfull `\hbox` on other places than the chapter page. Did this affect anything else?

Comment: @FilipEkberg You're not required to use TeX Gyre Termes: I used it just to replicate your picture.